# Format Date JSON Stringify

Tags: angular, typescript

I try formatting date using `JSON.Stringify` but `myDate` become like this `myDate: "\"2019-10-14T01:35:31.986Z\""`, when `console.log`. Actually, I want to display like this `myDate: "2019-10-14"`

**Component**

```
let out = this.form.value.myDate;
this.form.controls.myDate.patchValue(JSON.stringify(out));

onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.form.value);
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to submit form to backend with format date `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
out.toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

Considering myDate is always typeof Date